# Retrieve Image or any document from database using MVC pattern in java

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

My program is working, but JSP page loading very slow that is my issue. I am passing empid and image name as a parameter from a jsp page to a Servlet which I am able to do perfectly and it is receiving in Servlet and calling data access class associated method, after that I am retrieving it  and passing all this to JSP in JSP I am using Scriptlet inside that image is loading into JSP page but it is loading very slow at least 10-15 second and console showing below error :

```
EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MVCDemoProject] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this   response
```

EmployeeBean class method

```
  public Employee RetrieveImg(Employee emp1){
  Connection con = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  byte[] sImageBytes;
  int z = emp1.getEmpId();
  String q = emp1.getIname();
  try {
   int count =0;
     con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     String Query ="SELECT photo FROM upload_documets WHERE empId ='"+z+"' and Name ='"+q+"'";
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
           if(rs.next()) 
       {          sImageBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
                  emp1 = new Employee();
                  emp1.setFileBytes(sImageBytes);
               emp1.setValid1(true);     
       } 
  }catch (SQLException  ex) {

       } finally {
           try {
               if (stmt != null) {
                   stmt.close();
               }
               if (con != null) {
                   con.close();
               }
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }
    return emp1;
   }
```

Image retrieval servlet which is calling data access class(employee bean) method on the basis of input which we have received from jsp page (image name and emp id name)

```
   @WebServlet(name = "Retrieve_Image", urlPatterns = {"/Retrieve_Image"})
   public class Retrieve_Image extends HttpServlet {
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");

    String iname = request.getParameter("iname");
    emp1.setEmpId(emp1.getEmpId());
    emp1.setIname(iname);
    EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();
    eb.RetrieveImg(emp1);
    if(emp1.isValid1())
    {
         response.sendRedirect("Image.jsp");
    }

}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
  }
 }
```

jsp page after calling method where we want to see image response:

```
 <body>

 <%
Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
 session.setAttribute("emp1",emp1);

   byte[] sImageBytes;
   try{
  sImageBytes = emp1.getFileBytes();

  response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
   response.setContentLength(sImageBytes.length);
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"");

 BufferedInputStream  input = new BufferedInputStream
 (new ByteArrayInputStream(sImageBytes));
    BufferedOutputStream output =
   new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
   int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
 output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
 }
  catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println("error :"+ex);
    }
 %>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: categories all the classes separately. All are mixed and not properly aligned.

Comment: May be database access is taking time. What is the size of image?

Comment: Format your code first. no will help if other can not understand your code properly.

Comment: size is 250 kb so some issue is there...

Comment: @Yagnesh i have done some edit as you said..now is it helpful to you understand the problem

Comment: If this is for download file using JSP & servlet than this is not a good way. dont use scriplet it is old.

Comment: @Yagnesh i am calling one method which is in data access class their i am retrieving image and its type and adding into bean class object and trying to retrieve on jsp using scriptlet help me in this if you can..

Comment: You have a Servlet,in that you read your data from database, in output write this stream, same as you are doing in JSP.

Comment: ok i got it i am doing same thing twice in jsp and servlet both place so tell me what should i do in jsp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59644/discussion-between-yagnesh-and-sourav78611).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your jsp:-

```
<%@page language="java" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

Also do the below change:-

```
BufferedInputStream  input;
 BufferedOutputStream output;

........

   try{
       .........
  ............

    BufferedInputStream  input = new BufferedInputStream
     (new ByteArrayInputStream(sImageBytes));
        BufferedOutputStream output =
       new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

      int length;
      length = sImageBytes.length;    
      output.write(sImageBytes, 0, length);
    catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println("error :"+ex);
    } finally{
    if(output != null) {
       output.flush();
       output.close();
    }
    if(input != null) {
       input.close();
    }
```

Comment: bro its working in case of image but still showing some error message on console : getOutputStream() has already been called for this response and this is working for image but if it is different kind of document then it is not helpful like in case of pdf or excel any kind of document... so suggest something

Comment: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response, this problem is always coming either i am retrieving image or any other document,another issue is if i am trying to retrieve any other document instead of image it is not coming because we have given response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); so how to retrieve other documents, yea the loading jsp page is reduced it is loading quickly that is solved

Comment: @sourav78611 If you have pdf document to be downloaded then you need to set the correct mime type as "application/pdf". eg:- response.setContentType("application/pdf");
Please check this link for the appropriate mimetypes http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: bro read my comment i have done that already... previously without mvc i have done all this here i am using mvc... so what i did previously at the time of storing image or document i store type of document in contentType in table and at retrieving time i am using one variable in which again getting type of document and setting back to response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); here instead of image/jpeg i am passing that string variable which working without mvc here just tell me how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change below function code in Servlet :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{ 
        BufferedInputStream  input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;
        try
        {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
            Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1"); 

            String iname = request.getParameter("iname"); 
            System.out.println("...." +iname); 
            emp1.setEmpId(emp1.getEmpId()); 
            emp1.setIname(iname); 
            EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean(); 
            eb.RetrieveImg(emp1); 
            if(emp1.isValid1()) 
            { 
                response.setContentType(emp1.getContentType());
                response.setContentLength(sImageBytes.length);
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"");
                input = new BufferedInputStream (new ByteArrayInputStream(sImageBytes));
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

                response.getOutputStream().write(emp1.getFileBytes);
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(output != null) 
            {
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
            if(input != null) 
            {
                input.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

May this will help you.